# Generate App.config from template

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I trying to create tool to create app.config files for my end-users.

All the tool does is create connection strings and add them to a template app.config I already have, but I can't seem to save just the connection strings to my template. Instead I get a whole different app.config.

I've read about serializing the config to an XML object and saving it as an XML document but that would require mapping a lot of the config file when all I want is to insert connection strings.

Here is my code:

```
public Configuration CreateConfiguration(List<DatabaseConfig> databaseList)
{   
            var configurationPath = string.Format("{0}{1}", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"Resources\MyApplication.template.config");
        if (!File.Exists(configurationPath)) return null;

        //Open the app.config for modification
        var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(configurationPath);

        foreach (var database in databaseList)
        {
            //Retreive connection string setting
            var connectionString = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[database.Name];
            if (connectionString == null)
            {
                //Create connection string if it doesn't exist
                config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Add(new ConnectionStringSettings
                {
                    Name = database.Name,
                    ConnectionString = database.ConnectionString,
                    ProviderName = "System.Data.SqlClient"
                });
            }
            else
            {
                //Only modify the connection string if it does exist
                connectionString.ConnectionString = database.ConnectionString;
            }
        }

        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);
        //config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);

        // Display Folder Dialog (User chooses save location)
        var folderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var filePath = Path.Combine(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath, @"MyApplication.exe.config");
            config.SaveAs(filePath);
        }
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by you get a whole new app.config?

Comment: I want to create/save app.config, keeping the template untouched. right now the code creates a new config with the connection strings but nothing from the template is in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a regular expression or a simple string format to replace the connection string in the template file and save it as a new file.

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var database in databaseList)
{   
    builder.AppendFormat("<add name=\"{0}\" connectionString=\"{1}\" providerName=\"{2}\" />\n", database.name, database.connection, database.provider);
}
var templateContents = File.ReadAllText(templatePath);
var configContents = string.Format(templateContents, builder.ToString());
File.WriteAllText(configPath, configContents);
```

In your template file, you can simply put the following where the connection strings are supposed to go.

```
<connectionStrings>
    {0}
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: How would it handle multiple connection strings, depending on how many the user adds.

Comment: See updated answer to support multiple database connections.

Comment: I get a "Invalid String Format" error on the File.WriteAllText line.

Comment: Make sure that your template files contains the text in my answer with the {0} format.

Comment: My template file has other settings that use { } brackets, I think this is causing issues for string.Format.

Comment: Yes, this would cause issues for you. Try replace my string format logic with a regular expression.

Comment: Trying to figure that out now, would something like this work? https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/467403/replace-strings-between-specified-tags

Comment: Use something along the lines of Regex.Replace(templateContents, "\<connectionStrings\>\<\/connectionStrings\>", string.Format("<connectionStrings>{0}</connectionStrings>", builder.ToString());

Comment: Best bet with Regular Expressions is to first nail down the matching expression using a tester like http://regexstorm.net/ and then integrating it into your code.

Comment: Bam! Got it.... 

```
                const string pattern = @"<connectionStrings.*?>(.|\n)*?</connectionStrings>";
                var configContents = Regex.Replace(templateContents, pattern, string.Format("<connectionStrings>{0}</connectionStrings>", builder.ToString()));
```

Comment: Nice! Glad you sorted it out!